# html width 100% showing differently

Tags: html, width

I have been trying to find a cause for why my table width display differently when is different folder.

When i in this link it work perfectly fine and there isn't a border around it. [link](http://www.acekoncept.com.sg/test/)

But when i use the same table in 
[this link](http://www.acekoncept.com.sg/test/adm/test.php)

Anyone who have experience this and know what is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that in the second link page body have below code.

```
body {
display: block;
margin: 8px;
}
```

But in the first link page body have below code.

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i think i need to specify the margin on individual page to get it "truly 100%" in css, else the html processor will auto add in the margin.

Comment: Yes. Try always include reset css so you don't need to run into this problem.